# Чем можно заменить данную функцию, чтобы работала на версии >7.4

Tags: php

есть функция, которая проверяет является ли последний знак запятой

```
public function test(){
    $test = implode('',$this->columnNames);
    if($test{strlen(substr($test,0,-1))} == ','){
        $test = substr($test,0,-1);
    }
    
    return $test;
    }
```

phpstrom говорит, что 3 строка, где идет проверка на запятую, работает только на версии 7.4 или ниже. Как можно поменять, чтобы работало на более поздних версиях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($test{strlen(substr($test,0,-1))} == ','){
```

`Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported` Фигурные скобки при обращение к индексу заменить на квадратные скобки:

```
if ($test[strlen(substr($test,0,-1))] == ',') {
```

Если подумать о том происходит внутри, скорее всего, проще было бы обрезать все запятые "справа" с помощью `rtrim`:

```
public function test() {
    $test = implode('', $this->columnNames);
    $test = rtrim($test, ',');
    
    return $test;
}
```

Comment: Больше интересно, откуда в конструкции вида `implode('', ...`  взялась какая-то запятая в конце :D

Comment: делаю создания таблицы через ооп, и методы выглядит по типу array_push($this->columnNames,"$columnName ".'int PRIMARY KEY,'); в конце запятая, типо перечисление столбцов, и в конце уже, при создании таблицы, запятая обрезается, а то с ней не даст создать таблицу

Comment: @СергейАкимов *array_push($this->columnNames,"$columnName ".'int PRIMARY KEY,');* --- это **НЕ** ООП. ...... и если нужно было сделать что-то через запятую, то это как раз делается через `implode(',', ...)`